# Can't add data to HTML website using node-fetch post

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fetch

I have a code that creates a website with some JSON data and then I want to use node-fetch POST to overwrite this data (or append to it). However, after running the code the website still shows the initial data (`{"title":"clean room"}`) instead of the desired `{"title":"wash dishes"}`. I am running the website in Safari.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import http from 'http';

const PORT = 8080;

const text = JSON.stringify({
    title: "clean room"
});

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" });
    response.write(text);
    console.log(text);
    response.end();
}).listen(PORT);

fetch('http://localhost:8080', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "wash dishes"
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
```

How can I fix that?

EDIT: a guide that helped me solve my problem [Anatomy of an HTTP Transaction](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/https://)

Comment: Why would it show the "wash dishes" text? You've specifically coded it to respond with the contents of the `text` variable. And you've done nothing in the `fetch` to change that. If you want a POST to change the response, you have to put logic in your code to look at the `request`, see if it's a POST, validate the body, and set the variable that the code that responds to the GET returns. I suggest taking a tutorial on how to use the http library to do CRUD operations.

Comment: For starters, you could separate client and server code ... Your requesthandler does not return the content of `text` and does not do anything with the request's body. And the `fetch` should probably on the client side. Currently you are doing a request to the server within the server itself. That doesn't make much sense

Comment: Thank you! Modifying the createServer function solved my problem